# show ip history to login user

Tags: security, history

Show ip history, like last 100 logins IP and time, can be scare user?

I think maybe user think why service provider store my IP? of course after some storing we can have fraud detection

my solution until now is store everything but don't show user anythings, this is good? what is the best way to show user everything?

at all what is user interaction to see IPs? happy or scared?

Comment: What is the benefit to the user in displaying their last 100 IP addresses?

Comment: Do you really nead to stock that much history?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simpler approach that more users would understand would be to tell the user when they last logged in. Most users won't understand IP address (unless you have a very technical audience). Alternatively, you could display when the user last logged in, and if they select "Tell me more", explain about IP addresses and then display the information - but again - probably a technical user group only.

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on what service you are running to whether it is advantageous to show those details to users. With most services, I'd say that it is probably unnecessary. However, if you are building a service that needs to have added security controls, it can become handy. Say you have a service that stores business details for people inside the organisation to access. Allowing them to see their recent activity with IP addresses (or a approximate location using IPLookup services) is a good idea. You could incorporate features within this, such as remote logout - or even locking access down to a certain IP range only, if the users wants internal access only.

As I said, though, i think it depends on what service you are running and whether you think your users would want such a feature set.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother user with these details unless and until user has asked for these and you want

-- user to confirm that those logins were done by him and he will be able to report invalid logins and you will not be able to block that user's login next time from that IP

-- to award points to user for each login and you want user to be able to see his points history (and how he won those points)